# How to calculate the average point spacing for a layer of points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, distance, analysis, xyz

I have a set of points and want to calculate the average point spacing for further analysis.

ArcMap has the 3D Analyst Point File Information for this but I'm searching for an alternative in QGIS. Any ideas?

Comment: Use "Distance Matrix", under Vector->Analysis Tools

Comment: Thanks that helped. It first crashed several times but when I only used the 10 nearest target points it worked (I have nearly 4000 points in my layer)

Comment: @SecludedPath - You should post your comment as an answer =)

Comment: Thanks @Joseph, I know, but did not have the time to write a fully fledged one!